# Getting FormData as Null while transfer image file in Node JS API from IONIC

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I am getting `NULL` value in Node Js API for upload file through FormData in IONIC
Below is the IONIC code that read file from Pictures folder of phone and then append the value in FormData object and it passed through `http.post()` to Node Js API

IONIC component Code

```
getSynchAPICallForFileUpload =()=>{
this.file.listDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory,'Pictures').then(result=>{
   for(let file of result){
     if(file.isFile){

       let name = file.name
        if(name.indexOf('.png')){

          this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Pictures/'+file.name)
            .then(entry => {
              (<FileEntry>entry).file(file => this.readFile(file))
            })
            .catch(err => {

            });
        }
     }
   }
})}

  readFile=(file : any)=>{
this.getSetFormData(file).then(result=>{
   this.walkthroughservice.callApiForUploadFile(this.formData).subscribe(res => {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Data',
      subTitle: 'File Uploaded' + res,
      buttons: ['Ok']
    })
    alert.present()
  }) })

    getSetFormData = (file: any)=>{
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Data',
    subTitle: 'File Present' + file.name + file.size,
    buttons: ['Ok']
  })
  alert.present()
  this.formData = new FormData()
  this.formData.append('sampleFile',file)

 resolve(1)
}) }
```

Service Code

```
  callApiForUploadFile(formData: FormData) : Observable<any>{
this.apiUrl = "http://123.123.123.123/api/v1/upload"
return this.http
  .post(this.apiUrl, formData)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server error')) }
```

Node JS API Code

```
module.exports.uploadservice = (req,res,next)=>{
let options = req.headers.options
    ,db = options.db
    ,response = {
        "success":false,
        "message" : '',
        "path":''

    }
console.log('The Request Files',req.files)

let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile
console.log('The File Data Is',sampleFile.name)

return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    if (!req.files){
        response['success'] = false
        response['message'] = 'No files were uploaded.'
        response['path']=null
        return reject(response)
    }
    sampleFile.mv('/root/myapp/Prod/Documents/' + sampleFile.name, (error) => {
        if (error)
        {
            response['success'] = false
            response['message'] = 'No files were uploaded.'
            response['path']=null
            return reject(response)
        }else{
            response['success'] = true
            response['message'] = 'File uploaded!'
            response['path'] = '/root/myapp/Prod/Documents/' + sampleFile.name
            return resolve(response)
        }


     })
})
```

In the above code I am getting the `Null` value for `req.files` in API Side.
And in IONIC i am passing the FormData value.

Comment: Can you try `req.file` instead of `req.files` ?

Comment: Still get the same problem @ Amaranadh Meda

Comment: What is the middleware you are using ? I mean are using multer ? Can you share the code where you have configured the middleware ??

Comment: const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))
app.use(fileUpload())

Above is the my middle ware and I used express-fileupload.
@ Amaranadh Meda

Comment: I am sorry to asking you like this. Do you check the debugger while sending the request to the server? Seems like your server side code is fine. We need to check two things here. 1) debug the request your are sending 2) check once the router you have assigned in app.js is before the middleware or after the middleware

Comment: @AmaranadhMeda This API i tested with POSTMAN its works fine and it upload file successfully. And I also check with the Web Application it also able to upload the file in Sever. But While When i used this API for Mobile Application Then only I am getting undefine and Null value in req.files in API. and before Sending the file I append the file in formdata here i am getting the correct file size and name also. I don't know why API is not getting the FormData.

Comment: Okay. I think you need to check the mobile application http or ajax request code once.